# How to capture <table> contents using playwright

Tags: javascript, webautomation, playwright

What is the right query selector to grab all the  tags, and iterate, in order to capture table data? The below query selectors are failing to find the elements in the DOM. Thank you in advance

```
const allusers = await page.$$eval('tbody .MuiTableRow-root', (users) => {
    return users.map(user => {
        const email = user.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1)');
        const edition = user.querySelector('tr:nth-child(2)');
        return {
            email: email.innerText.trim(),
            edition: edition.innerText.trim()
        };
    });
});

console.log('${allusers.length} users found');
console.dir(allusers);
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Well, folks, as the saying goes, the devil is in the details.

Two things:

✔️ It's `:td`, not `:tr`, because `:td` is the child of `:tr`

✔️ There is no `innerText` on the element. We need to call access the value via `textContent`

Here's the working snippet:

```
const allusers = await page.$$eval('tbody .MuiTableRow-root', (users) => {
    return users.map(user => {
        const email = user.querySelector('td:nth-child(1)');
        const edition = user.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)');
        return {
            email: email.textContent.trim(),
            edition: edition.textContent.trim()
        };
    });
});

console.log(`${allusers.length} users found`);
console.dir(allusers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic version that waits for the table to exist:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>email</th><th>edition</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>foo@test.com</td><td>Core</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bar@test.com</td><td>Arm</td></tr>
    <tr><td>baz@test.com</td><td>Quux</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</body>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const data = await page.locator("table").evaluate(el => {
    const headers = [...el.querySelectorAll("th")].map(
      e => e.textContent
    );
    return [...el.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")].map(e =>
      Object.fromEntries(
        [...e.querySelectorAll("td")].map((e, i) => [
          headers[i],
          e.textContent,
        ])
      )
    );
  });
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```